# Why can't my Controller find my View Page? Spring Framework 404 error

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have just joined a company that using Spring Framework. I am used to using ASP.NET and for some reason I can't seem to get my controller to find the view.

It is using a redirect and selecting the name of a company to see what customers each company has(Yes ID would be better and in most places this company uses ID). However, for some reason, at their highest level, they left it to text.

The File Structure goes

Vendor

- VendorLandingPage
- EmployerList

Controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "{vendorName}/EmployerList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String VendorLandingPage(@PathVariable("vendorName") String vendorName, Map<String, Object> model)
{

   try{
  List<Customer> CustomerList = CustomerRepository.getCustomerList(vendorName);

    model.put("CustomerList", CustomerList);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       //Throw error..could not contact database
       //
   }


    //Owner owner = new Owner();
    //model.put("FileObject", owner);
    return "redirect:Vendor/EmployerList";
}
```

View Button Section

```
 <td>
                <spring:url value="{vendorName}/EmployerList.html" var="viewUrl">

                     <spring:param name="vendorName" value="${vendor.vendorName}"/>

                </spring:url>
                 <a href="${fn:escapeXml(viewUrl)}" class="btn btn-default">View Employer List</a>

            </td>
```

Comment: Is the class that VendorLandingPage is part of annotated with @Controller and do you have component-scanning setup?

Comment: Yes it is. I have another method that gets called, that is a "GET" version. That one works fine, the difference is the posting variable

Comment: The mistake may be in the <spring:url value="{vendorName}/EmployerList.html" var="viewUrl"> - Spring Web MVC cannot resolve "{vendorName}/EmployerList.html" to any view.

Comment: seems return "redirect:Vendor/EmployerList"; you are doing something. application is running into page that does not exist. probably you should 
return "EmployerList"; . And make sure you have added view resolvers http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver